Understanding Python's bisect Library: Clarifying Usage of bisect_left
During my recent work on a mathematical problem in Python, I encountered some confusion regarding the behavior of the bisect.bisect_left function from the bisect library. This confusion arose due to its similarity with another function in the library, namely bisect.insort_left.
In my specific use case, I was utilizing a custom key function, such as bisect.insort_left(my_list, my_item, key=my_key), which behaved as expected. This function determined the appropriate index for my_item in my_list using the specified key and inserted it accordingly.
However, when attempting a similar operation with bisect.bisect_left(my_list, my_item, key=my_key), I encountered an unexpected TypeError: "other argument must be K instance". This error message lacked clarity regarding the underlying issue.
Upon investigating the source code of bisect, I discovered the correct usage pattern, as indicated by line 71 of the source code. It became apparent that the correct usage involves calling the key function with the item as an argument, like so: bisect.bisect_left(my_list, my_key(my_item), key=my_key).
I am curious about the design decision behind this requirement. Why is it necessary to call my_key(my_item) when using bisect.bisect_left compared to the more straightforward usage in bisect.insort_left?

have you checked out the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Based on the discussion on the bug tracker for the issue that eventually led to this feature being added, it seems that bisect.bisect family of functions was designed to not call key on x and expect the desired key to be passed in as x instead, because bisect functions are typically called repeatedly.  insort on the other hand, needs both the element to be inserted and the key used to calculate the insertion point, so it will call key(x) internally.

Let's say the list items contain a lot of data. Each item can be e. g. a dict
{
    'id': 12,
    'firstname': 'foo',
    'lastname': 'bar',
    'address': ...,
    'phone': ...
    ...
}

These items are sorted in the list by id with an appropriate key function like lambda item: item['id'].
If you want to find an item with bisect_left it shouldn't be necessary to provide the whole item with all of its data but the id should be enough.
In the docs this is mentioned a bit cryptically:

To support searching complex records, the key function is not applied
to the x value.

If you want to insert an item with insort_left of course you have to provide the complete item with all data.
